# If $f(1)=2\int_{0}^{1/2}e^{1-x}f(x)dx$, prove that there exists $c\in(0,1)$ such that $f(c)=f'(c)$.

Tags: calculus

$f$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$ .
$$f(1)=2\int_{0}^{1/2}e^{1-x}f(x)dx\leq2e\int_{0}^{1/2}f(x)dx=ef(c_1)$$ where $c_1\in(0,1/2)$.
Then I thought of let $g(x)=e^{1-x}f(x)$, so when differentiated, it would yield $e^{1-x}(-f(x)+f'(x))$, which looks similar to the equation mentioned in the question--am I on the right track? How do I link them together? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $$F(x)=\int_{0}^{x} e^{1-x}f(x)$$
given $$\frac{f(1)}{2}=\int_{0}^{1/2}e^{1-x}f(x)dx$$
$$\frac{f(1)}{2}=F(1/2)$$
hence we see $F(1/2)=f(1)/2$, $F(0)=0$,$F'(1)=0$ thus by LMVT there exists some $d \in 0,1/2)$ for which $$F'(d)=\frac{F(1/2)-F(0)}{1/2}=f(1)$$,Now by rolles theorem  there is some $c \in (d,1/2)$ for which $$F''(c)=0$$.$$e^{1-x}(f'(c)-f(c))=0$$
$$f'(c)=f(c)$$

Comment: Why F(1/2)=f(1)/2?

Comment: @LeeLaindingold i have edited please see now